# Activiti Workflow Invocation from Java code

Tags: java, concurrency, process, runtime, activiti

I am creating an Activiti controller that can listen for messages and fork off the processes on demand.

I have been trying to use the java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ...");
```

as it works just fine when I run normal java executable jars, but in the case of running Activiti projects that are exported the call seems to hang until the Activiti controller completes.

Controller:

```
while(1){
    print "listening"
    recv message
    print "executing"
    exec process
    print "done"
}
```

When a message is received all of the prints display, including coming back to the top of the loop. But until I forcibly close the application, or remove the while loop entirely, the process does not actually run.

When the controller code is completed the entire Activiti jar can be seen completing in the command line.

** This is not simply holding the output and displaying it at the end, I know this because the workflow passes messages to other services which i can monitor for Activiti.

** I have tried using runnable and thread instead, placing the exec into another class and the same behavior is exhibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are reading stdout and stderr from the process.

Comment: the first thing the process does is send a message to another piece of software, that does not happen until the activiti controller is stopped/completed.  also, if i don't read from the getOutputStream() , getInputStream() , getErrorStream() it shouldn't block... right?

Comment: from the Java API of Process: All its standard io (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process through three streams (getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), getErrorStream()). The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

Comment: you have no idea how much i love you right now.  i didn't think that the error stream would block process execution.